# RazorGenerator not processing Html.EditorFor or Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following razor code:

```
<form id="logon" action="/security/dev" method="get">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" />
</form>
```

when getting the precompiled version to output the generated html I get the following:

```
  <form id="logon" action="/security/dev" method="get">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="vTyswnqonYMzGeewLrLSJ9XySz1A0PR0nvyVu58458J/nftXtxBPIVoQEdfr3MzEYPDLBPcGvXtMkOTujsou/x3eJVfdt2YSJgxUfu6AxMLj23kTwUNQo7X8ec7twsbt8U2BdogpHy0fSGq1nMljlukM9fGZ/770JLijcpJXx4o=" />
        /* EditorTemplates/String */

        /* EditorTemplates/Password */

        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" />
  </form>
```

Anyone have *any* idea why it would do that? Here is a failing example: [skydrive file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=b64a3ed1739ebbd3&resid=B64A3ED1739EBBD3!157&parid=B64A3ED1739EBBD3!149&authkey=!ACfYgKdTvLO4bKo)

Cheers

w://

Comment: are Username and Password properties strings?

Comment: Could you tell (show) us how the code inside your ActionResult that calls this View?
Is your View strongly typed to a ViewModel?

Comment: Humm…it’s hard to say what could cause this to happen…I mean…when you do a View/Source in your browser you don’t see the html controls…how strange! Perhaps you might want to quickly create a new MVC project, create a simple ViewModel and inside the Index() ActionResult of the HomeController make it return the View strongly typed to that ViewModel. If that works, at least you’ll start eliminating some problems. Btw, I’m only suggesting this in order to help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: cheers - but in general - there is no reason for this to not work? it is expected that it works right?

Comment: Yes, in general this should be working as it is something trivial. When things like that happen to me, I take a step back, create a new project and start doing baby steps until I find the problem. Each step of the way, I make sure everything works this way, when a problem occurs I know exactly where and when it started which greatly helps me figure out why. If all else fails, I come here and post :-) Btw…have you tried the baby steps in a new project? Do they work? If they work, gently start adding stuff to eventually reach your problem.

Comment: Oh and one last thing…are you in « edit » mode? I mean…have you tried (instead of EditFor) using simple TextBoxFor? If not, try it and see if that works

Comment: I have uploaded a failing example: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=b64a3ed1739ebbd3&resid=B64A3ED1739EBBD3!157&parid=B64A3ED1739EBBD3!149&authkey=!ACfYgKdTvLO4bKo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not part of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with EditFor. Using TextBoxFor instead helped me.